# TypeScript extend class from generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to extend another class with a class extended from its parent class. I want to override some functions of the child class, but I want this class to be generic. How can I do that?

```js
// This definition does not work.
class Foo<T extends Base> extends T {
    // Override child class (T) functions
}
```

Comment: You can't extend an unspecified generic type.  You *can* make a mixin like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wepaVW), which should give you the behavior you want. Does that work for you? If so I could write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] which clearly demonstrates the use case you need to support.

Answer (score 0):

A class can't extend from a type.

You can either:

- extend from another class. In case of an abstract class, you can either implement concrete methods in the abstract class or define abstract methods, which you implement in the extended class.

```js
abstract class Base {
  concreteMethod() {
   // implementation of the concrete method (can still be overwritten in child)
  }
  abstract abstractMethod(): void // must be implemented in child
}

class Foo extends Base {
  abstractMethod() {
    // implementation of the abstract method
  };
}
```

- or implement the methods (and properties) from an interface

```js
interface Base {
  prop1: string
  method(): void
}

class Foo implements Base {
  prop1: string;

  constructor() {
    this.prop1 = "hello world"
  }
  method() {
    // implementation of the method
  };
}
```